# Параленьная обработка данных

Tags: python-3.x, многопоточность, агрегация

Есть xml файл с ОЧЕНЬ большим объемом данных (~700-800 Mb) - его необходимо парсить и в качестве результата генерировать новый json файл, который отправляется Системе.

Время работы функции парсинга xml файла порядка 30-40 сек для вышеуказанных значений обьема данных (работа происходит в докер контейнере), что удовлетворяет "заказчика".

Сейчас обсасываю возможность разделения процесса парсинга на несколько параллельных - так как исходный файл содержит список сущностей со своими данными, я смогу каждую сущность обработать в своем процессе/потоке, потом данные агрегировать.

Так как я параллельными вычислениями в Питоне очень мало сталкивался, хотел бы спросить - стоит ли их использовать при такого рода задачах и если да, то какой подход лучше всего - threading или multiprocessing ? Также какие есть в Питоне подходы и решения по агрегированию результатов выполнения параллельных процессов ?

Comment: Поправьте опечатки пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как вопроса два, отвечу на первый: если Вы хотите получить выигрыш в производительности, используйте `multiprocessing`. `threading` позволяет только распараллелить выполнение задач, однако скорость их выполнения останется такой же, как и при последовательном подходе (читайте про [GIL](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Interpreter_Lock), чтобы понять почему).

Насчёт агрегирования результатов могу посоветовать использовать разделяемый всеми процессами контейнер, в который каждый из них будет писать данные по окончании своего выполнения. Естественно, используя при этом инструменты безопасного параллельного доступа к данным.

Comment: можно ли использовать в качестве "разделяемый всеми процессами контейнер" `multiprocessing.Queue` ?

Comment: @dreadangel Судя по его названию, да, для этого он и предназначен. Но сам не пользовался.