# Пример с multiprocessing и потоковая обработка xml

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

Всем привет,

Учитывая [мой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1014145/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85/1014148) по параллельной обработке массива xml, [разработал](https://pastebin.com/Bxi4dPdj), используя [примеры](https://tutorialedge.net/python/python-multiprocessing-tutorial/), мой каркас для многопроцессорного  обработчика.

Однако столкнулся с проблемой - почему-то запуская приложение, оно уже не заканчиваться - так и висит не доходя до строки 51.

Зная что звучит банально, но обращаюсь к вам гуру питона - не укажете на возможный источник ошибки?

P.S. Учитывая комментарий от @extrn - отдельное спасибо за идею с `multiprocessing.Pool`, появилось [это решение](https://pastebin.com/Q6LuDpdG), которое работает и возвращает данные. Однако могу ли снова повторить вопрос выше и подсказать что именно ошибочно в нем?

Comment: Чем вас не устроило использование пулов, описанных в той же статье? Меньше бойлерплейта меньше потенциальных ошибок (одна из которых у вас уже есть в фукнции `work_processor`). У вас все процессы запускаются одновременно. Сколько их - я не знаю, возможно гораздо больше чем хотелось бы. Пул решает в том числе и эту проблему. Способ с очередью там же назван в общем случае нежелательным, но в редких случаях неизбежным. так вот это не вам случай.

Comment: там xml порядка 300 Mb со списком сущностей с количеством ~2000-2300

Comment: Запускать процессов или потоков больше чем у вас ядер процессора - смысла особого нет. В редких случаях пара лишних потоков может дать несколько процентов прироста, но обычно наоборот - производительность немного снизится. А вот 2000 нагруженных процессов наверняка "нагнут" вашу систему. `multiprocessing.Pool()` по умолчанию как раз запускает количество потоков равное количеству ядер.